# One part of my code is faster than the other one, but they're almost the same

Tags: python, dictionary

When I put the snake to start going to the "►" direction, it goes faster than when I do it for "◄" and the same result for "▲" and "▼".

Actually, it literally teleports. Even if I see that it's doing the right way correctly by going from key to key.

Maybe it's doing the process without showing it, until the end.

Do you see any reasons why does that happen? Because I really don't see why.

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import keyboard
from time import sleep
import os

#Get to work

game_area = {}

#Random snake and apple start positions

apple = randint(0, 540)
snake_pos = randint(0, 540)

#Define positions

for x in np.arange(0,540,1):
    game_area[x] = '.'

#Insert Apple

game_area[apple] = 'Ó'

#Limit areas

game_area[0], game_area[59], game_area[60], game_area[119],game_area[120], game_area[179],game_area[180], game_area[239],game_area[240],game_area[299],game_area[300],game_area[359], game_area[360],game_area[419],game_area[420],game_area[479],game_area[480], game_area[539] = '╔','╗','║','║','║','║','║','║','║','║','║','║','║','║','║','║','╚','╝'

for x in range(1,59):
    game_area[x] = '═'

for x in range(481,539):
    game_area[x] = '═'

#Snake Class

class Snake:
    def __init__(self, length, position):
        self.length = length
        self.position = position

    def printar(self):
        print(self.length,self.position)

snake = Snake(1,snake_pos)
game_area[snake.position] = '►'

#Functions

def prepare_game():
    
    #Create game area

    for number, instance in zip(list(game_area.keys()), list(game_area.values())):
        
        if number not in [60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480]:
            print(instance, end='')
        
        else:
            print('\n' + instance, end='')
    
    print('')

def start_game():
    global game_area

    game_over = False

    while True:
        prepare_game()

        if game_over == False:
            
            #Keyboard Detect / Automatic Move
            
            if '◄' in list(game_area.values()):
                for x,y in game_area.items():
                    if y == '◄':
                        if game_area[x - 1] != '║':
                            game_area[x - 1] = y
                            game_area[x] = ' '
                        else:
                            game_over = True
                            break
            
            if '►' in list(game_area.values()):
                for x,y in game_area.items():
                    if y == '►':
                        if game_area[x + 1] != '║':
                            game_area[x + 1] = y
                            game_area[x] = ' '
                        else:
                            game_over = True
                            break

            if '▲' in list(game_area.values()):
                for x,y in game_area.items():
                    if y == '▲':
                        if game_area[x - 60] != '═':
                            game_area[x - 60] = y
                            game_area[x] = ' '
                        else:
                            game_over = True
                            break
            
            if '▼' in list(game_area.values()):
                for x,y in game_area.items():
                    if y == '▼':
                        if game_area[x + 60] != '═':
                            game_area[x + 60] = y
                            game_area[x] = ' '
                        else:
                            game_over = True
                            break

            if keyboard.is_pressed('up arrow'):
                pass

            if keyboard.is_pressed('left arrow'):
                pass

            if keyboard.is_pressed('right arrow'):
                pass

            if keyboard.is_pressed('down arrow'):
                pass

            if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
                break

            #End
            sleep(1)
            os.system("cls")
            continue
        else:
            break

start_game()
```

Comment: As an aside, `if '◄' in list(game_area.values())` is unnecessary. Just do ` if '◄' in game_area.values():`

Comment: Let's suppose that an arrow was found at index 5 in your list (just so I can give concrete numbers here).  If it was a left arrow, it moves to index 4; the inner loop then checks indexes 6, 7, etc. but does not find that arrow again.  But if it was a right arrow, it moves to index 6; the next iteration of the inner loop finds it at 6 and moves it to 7, then it finds it at 7 and moves it to 8, and so on.  Teleporting to the right margin is exactly what you've written here.  Iterating over a *copy* of the game area (so that you don't see arrows that were moved) would be one solution.